# How to access HttpServletRequest from vaadin UI class in vaadin 8

Tags: vaadin, vaadin8

In our vaadin 6 application, we can access the HttpServletRequest object from onRequestStart method from our vaadin Application sub-class.  We need to access the HttpServletRequest to obtain parameters passed by the caller which starts our vaadin application (an HTML Form). Now we are converting the application to vaadin 8.  I was not able to find a method in vaadin UI similar to onRequestStart that exposes the raw HttpServletRequest that starts the vaadin application.  I tried to use getParameter method of the VaadinRequest object passed to UI's init method, however, this could not retrieve the parameters passed. How can I get the parameters in the raw HttpServletRequest in vaadin 8?

Comment: I would like to first ask for what purpose you need to access HttpServletRequest, because that will determine what is the correct way to do it?

Comment: Our application is launched by another web app.  They pass us the authentication information as a FORM data (POST data).  If the VaadinServletRequest implementation adds all the parameters from the origianl HTTP request since it implements HttpServletRequest already, it will be good.  But that seems not to be the case, that's why I ask for access of the original HTTP request.  We did access original HTTP request in vaadin 6 from onRequestStart method of vaadin Application class.

Comment: Ok, based on your comment I see, that you do not actually have a need to access request from UI class. So you could use serviceInit and add there request handler via VaadinSession. Tricky part here is that you can consume FORM POST data only once (this restriction comes from HttpSession and HttpServletRequest themselves, not from Vaadin).

Comment: Thank you for the tip.  Can you provide some more details about how to use serviceInit?

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised that they can not be retrieved through `getParameter(...)`.

Since you're running on a servlet, the `VaadinRequest` will  be a `VaadinServletRequest`. After casting it to this subclass, you can use `getHttpServletRequest()` to get the wrapped request.

Comment: Vaadin 8 uses two-step initialization: the request that initializes the UI is not the same as the request that generates the bootstrap HTML.

Comment: I tried to use getHttpServletRequest() of VaadinServletRequest obj.  The object it returns appears not to be the original http request, instead, it's a VaadinServletRequest presumably the same one I can calling getHttpServletRequest() on.  This almost feels like a bug since the getHttpServletRequest() doesn't serve any purpose.  So the question remains as how to get the original http request.